# position:absolute incompatibility in Chrome and Firefox

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, firefox, incompatibility

My problem is this:
I have a form, and I put in this, of course, the `<input>`.
But in all inputs is having a little problem of compatibility between Chrome and Firefox. I believe that Chrome increases 2px on top compared to Firefox.
I'm going to pass code. What should I do? Using different values ​​in CSS for webkit and moz?
Here is my HTML:

```
<div id='FirstName_container'>
   <input type='text' name='FirstName' id='FirstName' value='' size='20' class='name1' placeholder="First name"/>
</div>
```

Here is the CSS:

```
#contact_form1 #FirstName_container {
    position:absolute;
    left:152px;
    top:12px;
    z-index:5;
}
```

What I can do? Thanks all in advance!

Comment: Can you tell exactly what is increased? I can see only one difference between Chrome and FF - it's placeholder position. http://jsfiddle.net/RGZch/

Comment: Have you tried setting margins and padding to 0 first

Comment: Morpheus: Chrome seems that increases 2px top compared to Firefox.
sam_7_h: no, I'll try it. Thanks.

Comment: use reset css when you going to start your design.

Comment: Sandeep: like this? http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/

Comment: sam_7_h: doesn't worked setting padding and margin 0.

Comment: I dont see any difference either, tested in FF and Chrome http://jsfiddle.net/AwMuh/ there must be some other style/element causing your problem...

Comment: @Gatekeeper Pull out your pixel ruler cause it's there.

Comment: Reset> if the one from E. Meyer doesn't work, a more specialized one like http://isellsoap.github.com/forms.css/ should do the trick (Chrome is really really f... err hard to (un-)style).

Comment: Gatekeeper: I saw in FF, comparing here Chrome and Firefox, have a incompatibility with top! Well, I'll take a print. Wait a minute.

Comment: Do you have to correct this 2px difference? If you've to align vertically with other blocks, OK it needs to be pixel-perfect in height but otherwise you're the **only** one to see your site on 2 different browsers. People won't notice that... They either use IE or Chrome or Firefox or Opera or Safari

Comment: Ok its there sory... I tried to set margin: 0px to input element and it worked, div shrinked from 26px height to 22px... try it http://jsfiddle.net/AwMuh/1/

Comment: Please all see the problem. I calculated, and how I felt, exactly two pixels of difference!
http://img607.imageshack.us/img607/4907/problemp.png

Comment: @FelipeAls hehehe I know, but I'm a perfectionist. This issue does not bother me much. I just would like to solve it! But if not, I will not mind.

Comment: I do not think it will take to resolve. Better hope that browsers correct this mismatch between them.

Answer (score 3):

Put this at the top of your CSS.

```
*
{
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}
```

This will make all margins and paddings default to zero. I add this to the beginning of every project and then I change individual margins or paddings when I need to.

Comment: Please all see the problem. I calculated, and how I felt, exactly two pixels of difference!
http://img607.imageshack.us/img607/4907/problemp.png

Comment: Yeah I know. I agree that it's two pixels difference.

Answer (score 0):

By using below you are giving #FirstName_container a position absolute:

```
#contact_form1 #FirstName_container {
    position:absolute;
    left:152px;
    top:12px;
    z-index:5;
}
```

You should give the parent of #FirstName_container a position relative and left and top values. That should help fix this.

```
#contact_form1{position:relative;top:XXpx; left:XXpx;}
```

Comment: But this will only move the position of the whole form. The difference of 2 pixels remain there.

Comment: And this problem of 2 pixels is in all the form elements.

Answer (score 0):

Most common errors created when using span instead of div with absolute position.
If you use div elements you'll generally see a better compatibility to all browsers from my experience.

Answer (score -3):

I managed to solve the problem! Just added `margin: 0;` across all elements.
Thanks to everyone who helped.

Comment: Lol         Lol  Lol  Lol  Lol  Lol  Lol